# Generate new array from sparse array of objects in JQ

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file that I want to process with JQ. It has an array of objects inside another object, with a key that I want to use to populate a new array.

In my real use-case this is nested in with a lot of other fluff and there lots more arrays but take this as a simpler but representative example of the kind of thing:

```
{
  "numbers": [
    {
      "numeral": 1,
      "ordinal": "1st",
      "word": "One"
    },
    {
      "numeral": 2,
      "ordinal": "2nd",
      "word": "Two"
    },
    {
      "numeral": 5,
      "ordinal": "5th",
      "word": "Five"
    },
    {
      "some-other-fluff-i-want-to-ignore": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to use JQ to get a new array based on the elements, ignoring some elements and handling the missing ones. e.g.

```
[
  "The 1st word is One",
  "The 2nd word is Two",
  "Wot no number 3?",
  "Wot no number 4?",
  "The 5th word is Five"
]
```

Doing this in a loop for the elements that are there is simple, terse and elegant enough:

```
.numbers | map( . | select( .numeral) | [ "The", .ordinal, "word is", .word ] | join (" "))
```

But I can't find a way to cope with the missing entries. I have some code that sort-of works:

```
.numbers | [
  ( .[] | select(.numeral == 1) | ( [ "The", .ordinal, "word is", .word ] | join (" ")) ) // "Wot no number 1?",
  ( .[] | select(.numeral == 2) | ( [ "The", .ordinal, "word is", .word ] | join (" ")) ) // "Wot no number 2?",
  ( .[] | select(.numeral == 3) | ( [ "The", .ordinal, "word is", .word ] | join (" ")) ) // "Wot no number 3?",
  ( .[] | select(.numeral == 4) | ( [ "The", .ordinal, "word is", .word ] | join (" ")) ) // "Wot no number 4?",
  ( .[] | select(.numeral == 5) | ( [ "The", .ordinal, "word is", .word ] | join (" ")) ) // "Wot no number 5?"
]
```

It produces usable output, after a fashion:

```
richard@sophia:~$ jq -f make-array.jq < numbers.json
[
  "The 1st word is One",
  "The 2nd word is Two",
  "Wot no number 3?",
  "Wot no number 4?",
  "The 5th word is Five"
]
richard@sophia:~$
```

However, whilst it produces the output, handles the missing elements and ignores the bits I don't want, it's obviously extremely naff code that cries out for a for-loop or something similar but I can't see a way in JQ to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**jq** solution:

```
jq 'def print(o): "The \(o.ordinal) word is \(o.word)";
    .numbers | (reduce map(select(.numeral))[] as $o ({}; .["\($o.numeral)"] = $o)) as $o
    | [range(0; ($o | [keys[] | tonumber] | max)) 
       | "\(.+1)" as $i
       | if ($o[$i]) then print($o[$i]) else "Wot no number \($i)?" end
    ]' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  "The 1st word is One",
  "The 2nd word is Two",
  "Wot no number 3?",
  "Wot no number 4?",
  "The 5th word is Five"
]
```

Comment: Thanks. This enabled me to fix my ugly code pretty easily. The string building is also neater than I had it.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution !

```
jq  '[ 
       range(1; ( .numbers | max_by(.numeral)|.numeral ) +1 ) as $range_do_diplay  | 
       .numbers as $thedata | $range_do_diplay |
       . as $i | 
            if ([$thedata[]|contains( { numeral: $i })]|any ) 
            then 
               ($thedata|map(select( .numeral == $i )))|.[0]| "The \(.ordinal) word is \(.word) " 
            else 
               "Wot no number \($i)?" 
            end  
     ] ' numbers.json
```

This solution use

- **max_by** to find the max value of *numeral*
- **range** to generate a list o values
- use variables to store intermediate value

Comment: Also some useful tips, thanks. Interesting difference to between this and RomanPerekhrest's answer if there are multiple elements with the same index (which in my case should never happen).